# GLMM - how unbalanced is unbalanced, how under-dispersed is under-dispersed?

Tags: unbalanced-classes, glmm, underdispersion

I have a large data set, with vegetation data sampled at plots that are Sand or Clay soil type at 20 sites. I plan to fit a GLMM to the data, with 'soil type' as both a fixed effect and as a random effect nested within site (i.e. glmer(response~soil-type + (1|Site/Soil-type). There is some imbalance among sites in terms of the total number of plots per site, there is also some imbalance within sites in terms of the proportion of clay to sand soil types sampled. For example, a well-replicated and balanced site has 49 clay, 49 sand plots. A poorly replicated and unbalanced site has 3 Clay and 11 Sand plots. I understand GLMMs can handle unbalanced designs fairly well. But there must be a limit. Given I am dealing with a large dataset and can afford to trim off some sites, is there any kind of a cut-off level of low-replication/extreme unbalance that I can go by to remove sites from the dataset. Also, I know underdispersed models are conservative, thereby reducing lieklihood of Type 1 error, but is there a cut-off for level of underdispersion where we would seek to address the cause of  problem of underdispersion. Initial modelling on my dataset indicates a OD stat of 0.75....